# Why [calendar dateFromComponents:] always return hour 16 ?

Tags: ios, nsdate

When I pass the [NSDate date] to NSDateComponents , then pass back after the weekday modified, I always got the hour 16:00:00 . Why ?

Code belows:

```
     {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"now = %@",now);

        NSDateComponents *firstDayOfWeek = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:now];
        firstDayOfWeek.weekday = 1; // Monday as first day of week

        NSDate *firstDayOfWeekDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstDayOfWeek];
        NSLog(@"first day = %@", firstDayOfWeekDate);
    }

    {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"now = %@",now);

        NSDateComponents *firstDayOfWeek = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:now];
        firstDayOfWeek.weekday = 1; // Monday as first day of week
        firstDayOfWeek.hour = 1;
        firstDayOfWeek.minute = 1;
        firstDayOfWeek.second = 1;

        NSDate *firstDayOfWeekDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstDayOfWeek];
        NSLog(@"first day = %@", firstDayOfWeekDate);
    }
```

And the output is :

```
 now = 2016-01-18 03:14:08 +0000
 first day = 2016-01-17 16:00:00 +0000
 now = 2016-01-18 03:14:08 +0000
 first day = 2016-01-17 17:01:01 +0000
```

Why the hour begins with 16 ?

Comment: Is your timezone in UTC+8? If so, the output is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDateComponents` isn't making it `16:00:00`. It's making it midnight in your current timezone. But the `NSLog` is showing you the equivalent GMT time. That's what the `+0000` means: e.g. GMT +00:00.

Bottom line, if you want to see the resulting `NSDate` object in your local time zone, you should use `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to timezone.

Try to add `NSDateFormatter` before you output the date with `NSLog`, e.g.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *dateDisplay = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfWeekDate];
NSLog(@"first day = %@",dateDisplay);
```

You can refer [this article](http://coding-is-kind-of-magic.blogspot.my/2012/02/converting-nsdate-to-nsstring.html) for more examples.